# Cannot update object property via the Update Method in PowerBI Development Tools

Tags: powerbi

I am still a beginner in developing Power BI and 
I have a problem when using "Power BI Development Tools".
( https://app.powerbi.com/devTools )

The problem is that "I cannot update object property via the update method".

For example, I have created two objects in the body,
which are "one rectangle" and "one text object".
And in order to apply the selectAll method, I used selectAll method in the rectangle object. (For example, if the input datapoints increases, it is supposed to be more rectangles)

In both objects, I wrote the "++this.count" in their property,
supposing both objects will change the words(text object) or the width(rectangle object) when either clicking on the window or re-sizing the window.

However, it turned out to be a different result.
The words of text object changed but the width of rectangle object did not change while either clicking on the window or re-sizing the window.

I would like to ask for help since I think I must have some concept misunderstanding but I do not know where to start to exploring is better.

Can anyone tell me
(1) why only one object changed(updated) in the update method ?
(2) In which part of my concept is wrong ?

Thank you very much.

Following are the codes.

---

module powerbi.visuals {
    export interface TestData {
        date_value: Date
    }

```
export class Test implements IVisual {
    public static capabilities: VisualCapabilities = {
    };

    private element: JQuery;
    private body: D3.Selection;
    private Debug: D3.Selection;
    private svg: D3.Selection;
    private TT: D3.Selection;
    private RR: D3.Selection;
    private selectionManager: utility.SelectionManager;
    private dataView: DataView;
    private count = 0;

    public init(options: VisualInitOptions): void {
        var element = options.element;
        this.body = d3.select(element.get(0))
            .append('div');
        this.TT = this.body.append('text')
        this.svg = this.body.append('svg')
    }


    public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
        var width = options.viewport.width;
        var height = options.viewport.height;
        this.body.attr({ 'height': height, 'width': width });


        // Text Object
        this.TT
            .attr("x", 10 * ++this.count)
            .attr("y", 10 * ++this.count)
            .text('  width = ' + options.viewport.width + '...count = ' + + (++this.count))


        // Rectangle Object
        // use d3.selectAll method --> as datapoints increases, the number of  rectangles will also increase.
        var rectangle = this.svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data([1]);

        rectangle.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("y", 10)
            .attr("x", 20)
            .attr('width', 50 + ((++this.count)))
            .attr('height', 100)
            .attr('fill', 'red')

        rectangle.exit().remove()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only set the rectangle width/height on the D3 enter event, that's when it's first added to the page. Look at the [enter selection code example](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#enter) that show how to update both new and existing nodes (it's the last one before the exit event).

So you need to change your code for enter to do something like:

```
var rectangle = this.svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data([1]);

rectangle.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("y", 10)
            .attr("x", 20);

rectangle.attr('width', 50 + ((++this.count)))
            .attr('height', 100)
            .attr('fill', 'red');

        rectangle.exit().remove();
```

Comment: Hi Lukasz, thank you for your help. I understood my concept was wrong, and it is successful now. Thank you so much!!